# Retrieve escaped XML and unescape using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping, xslt-1.0

I am calling a web service that embeds the response XML as escaped XML. I'm receiving the complete SOAP response, but am only interested in the 'escaped XML' portion (`<SendMessageResult>`).

**I'm trying to write a XSL (1.0) to retrieve that escaped XML and unescape it**, so I can process it via other non-XSLT components.

I have tried some of the other solutions for 'unescaping' in StackOverflow, but with no luck.

Response from Web Service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <SendMessageResponse xmlns="http://www.company.com/CAIS">
            <SendMessageResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;&lt;IEXInboundServiceResponse&gt;&lt;IEXInboundServiceResponseVersion&gt;1.0&lt;/IEXInboundServiceResponseVersion&gt;&lt;ServiceResponse&gt;IEX_SUCCESS&lt;/ServiceResponse&gt;&lt;RequestMessageId&gt;22658651-024E-445B-96C1-94F027205E01&lt;/RequestMessageId&gt;&lt;/IEXInboundServiceResponse&gt;</SendMessageResult>
        </SendMessageResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Desired output after unescaping

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<IEXInboundServiceResponse>
    <IEXInboundServiceResponseVersion>1.0</IEXInboundServiceResponseVersion>
    <ServiceResponse>IEX_SUCCESS</ServiceResponse>
    <RequestMessageId>22658651-024E-445B-96C1-94F027205E01</RequestMessageId>
</IEXInboundServiceResponse>
```

Current XSLT I am using

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="//SendMessageResult">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And do you wish to show the XSL you have tried so we can help point to the area to correct?

Comment: Hi Kevin,I have edited the original post to include the XSLT I have been using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is to deal with the namespacing you are using. First of all, you haven't declared the `http://www.company.com/CAIS` namspace in your XSLT. You can fix this by changing the first line to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                 xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                 xmlns:c="http://www.company.com/CAIS">
```

Note the last namespace. I tried with a blank namespace but it continued to have the same issues as you had.

Then change the opening line of the template to:

```
<xsl:template match="//c:SendMessageResult">
```

Then it should work as expected.